# How to show random post order in specific category each refresh this category page

Tags: posts

help me, please Im biginner.
I want to show a random post order in specific category each refresh this page, any advice and suggestions will be greatly ppreciated.

for this url - http://bitly.kr/9gahbD

thanks, everyone.

Comment: For displaying random post order you can use 'orderby'   => 'rand' in your loop.

Comment: sorry, what is the mean "in your loop"?